# Output field separator in ipcalc

Tags: text-formatting

On linux,I use ipcalc and its output is separated by "=" like this:

```
# ipcalc -n 192.168.1.1/24

NETWORK=192.168.1.0
```

but I find some material the output is separated by ":" like this:

```
# ipcalc 10.132.58.121/255.255.240.0
Address: 10.132.58.121 00001010.10000100.0011 1010.01111001
Netmast: 255.255.240.0 = 20 11111111.11111111.1111 0000.00000000
....
```

so why and how I can make the output separated by ":" ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on the ipcalc version installed in your OS. Mine (Ubuntu), the output is given with ":".

You can change the characters with `sed` as follows:

```
sed -e 's/=/: /g'
```